# Including an iframed WYSIWYG editor in a form submit

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg

I am trying to include a WYSIWYG editor in a form that is ultimately sent via AJAX to the server.  The problem is that serializing the form doesn't include the editor input because it's being rendered in an iframe on the page.  This seems to be the way that "all" the editors do it (I've only tried 4).

My question is:

1.) How to include or retrieve the iFramed WYSIWYG edit field in a the serialized form for POSTing

or

2.) Is there a basic WYSIWYG HTML editor that *doesn't* use the iFrame approach, and would render an input field in the form that is being POSTed

Comment: You can get contents from all wysiwyg editors like i.e. ckeditor.

Comment: Why don't you want to use iframes?

Comment: Are you using an editor that attaches to a textarea? If so, just make sure the textarea has a name attribute and it should serialize. Most editors I've seen attach to a textarea and create their own iframe interface

Comment: not opposed to iframes, but the rendered input area is being omitted from the form that is serialized and submitted.  My assumption was that it was due to being with an iframe, and not within the form tags.  Was useing mceEditor, and started with ckeditor, but it's the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use CKEditor (as you state that you have tested), you can call [updateElement](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#updateElement) before serializing the form and the textarea will have the current data, or you can retrieve it by calling [getData](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData).

For normal submits that operation is automatic, but as you're not using the form submit, then it won't work on its own.